# What are applications of HHL's "simple example" to determine similar stable states of different quantum processes?

Tags: quantum-algorithms, hhl-algorithm

The HHL paper "Quantum algorithm for linear systems of equations" [[link](https://arxiv.org/abs/0811.3171)] initially describes a "simple example" to illustrate the potential power of their algorithm.

They state:

> Consider a stochastic process $x_t=Ax_{t−1}+b$, where the $i$’th coordinate in the vector $x_t$ represents the abundance of item $i$ in time $t$. The stable state of this distribution is given by $\vert x\rangle = (I−A)^{−1}\vert b\rangle$. Let $x_t'=A'x_{t−1}'+b'$, and $\vert x'\rangle = (I−A')^{−1}\vert b '\rangle$. To know if $\vert x\rangle$ and $\vert x'\rangle$ are similar, we perform the $\mathsf{SWAP}$ test between them.

If I understand this correctly, this seems like a very potent application of HHL.

That is, if we have some large space that we *know* can be fully explored with a certain set of moves $s= \langle P, Q, R\rangle$ but we *suspect* can be fully explored with a simpler set of moves $s'=\langle P, Q \rangle$, then I believe as long as we have some way to prepare $\vert b\rangle$ and $\vert b' \rangle$ in a uniform superposition of the entire space, we can determine if both $s'$ generate as big a space as $s$.

For example, it's debated whether the Rubik's Cube can be generated with only $5$ of the $6$ twists - that, whether one of the twists is redundant.  If we define $A$ to correspond to a transition matrix flipping all $6$ of the faces, while $A'$ is defined to be only $5$ of the faces, and we let both $\vert b \rangle$ and $\vert b' \rangle$ be in a uniform superposition over all of the Rubik's cube states, then I believe running the HHL embodiment described above will answer whether that $6^{\text{th}}$ face twist is redundant.

As another example, we know that knot moves on a grid diagram - including cyclic permutations, stabilizations, and castling moves - are sufficient to tie and untie any knot to any other knot.  However, I read somewhere that cyclic permutations may be redundant, and be realized by a sequence of castling and stabilization/destabilization moves.  If we are able to generate a uniform superposition over all grid diagrams, and have $A$ be the transition matrix including permutations and $A'$ be the transition matrix excluding permutations, then I believe we would show the same.

**Is this the correct way to think about the HHL paper's example?  Are there other good examples of HHL's reasoning?**

Comment: I wouldn't really call this an "application of HHL" though. It is a possible use of being able to invert linear systems, and HHL is an algorithm to improve the efficiency of such operation. Your examples, if correct, would work just the same by solving the linear system classically.

Comment: @glS thanks! As HHL emphasize it's hard to think of solving linear systems classically *without* in the end knowing $x_i$ for each and every $i$. I was trying to put my head around a big problem, where $A$ is sparse and can be easily described, that doesn't require such knowledge of each and every $x_i$.